# How to mathematically determine row, column, and sub-square of cell in nxn array where n is a perfect square?

Tags: algorithms, arrays, square-grid

Given an one dimensional array of size nxn, where n is a perfect square

[image: Pic 1]

How can one mathematically determine the row, column, and/or sub-square the cell resides in? Additionally, is there a mathematical way to traverse the subsquare?

[image]

Comment: Try `x mod n` for the column and `x div n` for the row. Et cetera.

Comment: If the first cell on the first row in cell 0, the last cell on the first row should be cell **n-1**. Did you say cell n?

Comment: That's right @JohnL., my mistake.

Comment: Fixed. Was easier to update the first cell than all the rest.

Comment: Makes the calculation harder though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the one-dimensional cells be $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_{n^2}$.

Assume the top-left cell is at $(1,1)$, i.e., the first row and the first column. Assume the top right cell is at $(1,n)$, i.e., the first row and the $n$-th column. Then the $i$-th cell, $c_i$ is at $(i/n + 1, i \%n +1)$. Here $i/n$ is the *integer division* and $i\%n$ is the modulo operation in any popular programming language.  For example, let $n=9$. Then the $42$-th cell, $c_{42}$ is at $(42/9+1, 42\%9+1)=(5, 7)$.

Suppose the subsquares are lined up in the same order as the cells, so that we have subsquares $S1, S2, \cdots, Sn$. Consider each subsquare as a kind of "large cell". So that we would have the following coordinates for subsquares.

[image]

Note that $c_i$ belongs to the $(i/n+1)$-th subsquare, i.e. subsquare $S(i/n+1)$. For example, $c_{37}$ belongs to the $5$-th subsquare, i.e, subsquare $S5$. We are in the same situation as before, but with the $(i/n+1)$-th "large cell" and a $\sqrt n\times\sqrt n$ of "large cells". So similarly we see that the $(i/n+1)$-th subsquare is at $((i/n+1)/\sqrt n + 1,(i/n+1)\%\sqrt n + 1)$, using the coordinates for subsquares.

Suppose we want to traverse the subsquare at $(j,k)$ (where $(j,k)$ is in the coordinates for subsquares).

- The first cell (the top-left cell) of that subsquare is $c_{(j-1)\sqrt n\cdot n + (k-1)\sqrt n +1}$
- The first cell of the second row of that subsquare is $c_{(j-1)\sqrt n\cdot n + (k-1)\sqrt n +1 + n}$
- $\cdots$
- The first cell of the last row of that subsquare is $c_{(j-1)\sqrt n\cdot n + (k-1)\sqrt n + 1 + (\sqrt n -1 )n}$

So we can traverse all cells in that subsquare by the following pseudocode.

$\quad$ for $row$ in $1, 2, \cdots, \sqrt n$
$\quad\quad$ for $column$ in $1, 2, \cdots, \sqrt n$
$\quad\quad\quad$ visit the cell at $row$-th row and $column$-th column of the subsquare at $(j,k)$, which is $c_{(j-1)\sqrt n\cdot n + (k-1)\sqrt n + (row -1 )n + column}$

Note "$row$-th row and $column$-th column" are referring to cells in that subsquare.

For example, we will traverse the cells at subsquare (2,3) in the following order.

- cells in its first row, $c_{34}$, $c_{35}$, $c_{36}$,
- cells in its second row,  $c_{43}$, $c_{44}$, $c_{45}$,
- cells in its third row,  $c_{52}$, $c_{53}$, $c_{54}$.

Comment: It might have been clearer had we replace $n$ with $m^2$ and $\sqrt n$ with $m$ everywhere.

Comment: _Suppose we want to traverse the subsquare at (j,k).

The first cell (the top-left cell) of that subsquare is c((j−1)∗n√+k−1)∗n√+1_

Using the following values for (j,k) I get these results:

(1,4)=10
(4,4)=37
(7,4)=68

I'm assuming (j,k) is (row, column) of top left square?

Comment: @MDMoore313 I just clarified my answer.

Comment: Hmm, my illustration should have used $\sqrt n$ instead of 3.

Comment: Ahh, yes that does clear it up, thank you